# Updating fields under history tracking through unlocked package release

Tags: salesforcedx, field-history

We have one unlocked package that originally had some fields under history tracking and was released in production correctly. After a while we decided to add some more fields under history tracking, however when releasing the newer version of the unlocked package to our production org, those fields do not appear under history

Is there a known issue on field history tracking updates in unlocked packages?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is a known issue. This restricts without being released/promoted. As soon as you create a new version it will stop overriding the field history(either addition/removal).

We had case raised with Salesforce, and we received a link (which looks irrelevant), however as per the salesforce it's a feature request and they're working on it.

Link - https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?Id=a1p3A000001SHEU